# c++ found an example on splitting strings trying to figure out why change to it changes result

Tags: c++

I'm learning about splitting strings for a program in class, and i came across this example.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "23454323 ABCD EFGH";

    std::istringstream iss(str);

    std::string word;
    while(iss >> word)
    {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

I modified so that the user instead inputs the string,but if I input the string stored in str i get 23454323 and not the other material in the string.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"Enter a postfix with a space between each object:";
    cin>>str;
    istringstream iss(str);

    string word;
    while(iss >> word)
    {
        cout << word << '\n';
    }
}
```

Ok, thanks for the help everyone got it!

Comment: `std::cin >> str;` acts the exact same way as `iss >> word`.

Comment: I assume this is all related to [the same assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19641705/how-to-push-a-string-into-a-stack-one-element-at-at-time).

Comment: `cin >> str` will read up to first whitespace, and "eat" that whitespace.  So, you're giving the algorithm much different input in the second case.  Running through each line in a debugger would help.  So would reading about each method you are using in a C++ API reference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your input code a little for this to work. Use:

```
getline(cin, str);
```

instead of:

```
cin >> str;
```

The latter will stop reading a string on whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the same input operator as for `istringstream` when you input from `cin` and it always breaks on whitespace.

That means you only read a single word from the user. You want to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

Just as `iss >> word` reads a single space-separated word from `iss`, so `cin >> str` just reads the first word from `cin`.

To read a whole line, use `getline(cin, str)`.

<sub>(Also, get out of the habit of dumping `namespace std` into the global namespace. It will cause problems as your programs grow.)</sub>